# Where is hedera token / topic metadata housed?

Tags: blockchain, metadata, hedera-hashgraph

If I were to pass in a JSON object with metadata (ie. key=value pairs) to hedera's token / topic creation API, would a mirror node consume these metadata values as part of the transactions it captures from Hedera in order to allow for fast / efficient querying of this metadata?  Or would the metadata always be housed on IPFS which would lead to less than efficient querying of this metadata?

I've searched on the web and chatgpt seems to think the mirror node would include the metadata though that doesn't seem to align with Hedera's literature.  I've not attempted to deploy a mirror node yet and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata field on an NFT is a field where you can include any information you want. Typically, people include the actual metadata on IPFS and provide a link to it because the metadata field size is limited to 100 bytes. However, it's also possible to include the actual metadata in the field, depending on how your application processes the information. If your application can retrieve the metadata directly from the field, it should work fine. Mirror nodes don't interpret the field, so it doesn't matter if you include a URL or the actual message.